# Image Rotate on mousemove in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I have found this great bit of code via Stackoverflow to rotate a picture on mouse movement.

```
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
var offset = img.offset();
function mouse(evt){
    var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
    img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
}
$(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

Works fine on Firefox and Chrome but unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE 10

Here's a fiddle (I just changed the picture) : http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/225/

Any idea how to fix it ? Or should I just get over the fact that it won't work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE10 does not need the `-ms-` prefix for `transform`. The IE10 previews required it, but not the final release version of IE10.

Therefore, the answer is simply to remove the `-ms-` prefixing you've been using, and just set the base `transform` style:

```
img.css('transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
```

You should be doing this anyway -- even browsers that use prefixes are supposed to remove support for them later once the standard unprefixed version is established, so you should always specify the unprefixed version of a style as well, wherever you use a prefix.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/22Feh/225/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this `img.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');`

if you look here http://caniuse.com/transforms2d IE10 Doesn't need a prefix. I'm not sure if it accept's a prefix, but it's worth a try

Comment: This works. @user2595109, add this line to the function mouse(evt) before the  img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)'); line

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I hoped it would be as simple as that :)